# How to get value of enum without generic type statement?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

In normal way I define this function to get an enum value:

```kotlin
fun <T : Enum<T>> Class<T>.enumValue(name: String): T {
    return java.lang.Enum.valueOf(this, name)
}
```

But sometimes I don't know actual type of given `Class<*>` parameter:

```kotlin
fun String.toObject(type: Class<*>): Any {
    if (type.isEnum) {
        // Error: Type mismatch.
        // Required: Enum<TypeVariable(T)!>!
        // Found: Any!
        return java.lang.Enum.valueOf(type, this)
    }
    return this
}
```

`String.toObject` convert `String` to `Object` if given `type` is an enum type, but an error occurs:

```
Error: Type mismatch.
Required: Enum<TypeVariable(T)!>!
Found: Any!
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you can cast the type to `type as Class<Enum<*>>`

Comment: @sidgate Is there a more elegant way? cast will occure a yellow warning

Comment: The compiler isn't sophisticated enough to tell if this is a safe cast so it shows the warning. Since you can see that the class is obviously an Enum by the `isEnum` check, it's safe to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `type`

```
type as Class<Enum<*>>
```

Compiler gives warning, but you just have to ignore it as compiler cannot tell if it is a safe cast. As Tenfour04 mentioned you are already validating the type with `isEnum` hence it is safe to suppress the warning.